# How to create Tabbed interface to display the gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to Create Tabbed interface to display the Grid view when i click a tab button in asp.net code behind c#.

Comment: No need to insist on urgency. That's not our problem. It's yours. Should have asked earlier before it becomes urgent. What you have to insist on is to better describe your scenario, provide some code that you have tried to solve the problem that didn't work, explain how the actual results differed than the expected results, ... Only then you can expect answers. You may read the following for more info: http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: Hi,Thank you for giving response and good suggestion to me .Any way i get the answer for tabbed interface if anybody wants tabbed interface please refer this link(http://www.codeproject.com/KB/ajax/AJAXTabControl.aspx). And all of you thank you to give response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this :

[Creating a tabbed Gridview in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1603375/creating-a-tabbed-gridview-in-c)